# Enumerate a list with two parallel prefixes

Tags: enumerate

I want to enumerate a list like:

```
A1, B1, A2, B2,...An, Bn
```

Is it possible?

My list should result in

```
A1. First Item
B1. Second Item
A2. Third Item
B2. Fourth Item
```

Comment: Will the A and B always aternate ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Defining two counters `Ax` and `Bx` could be a solution, effectively using `\item[\theAx]` and `\item[\theBx]` after incrementing them each time they are used... defined in the preamble as `\itemA` and `\itemB` respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{Ax}
\newcounter{Bx}

\newcommand{\itemA}{%
    \addtocounter{Ax}{1}
    \item[A\theAx.]}
\newcommand{\itemB}{%
    \addtocounter{Bx}{1}
    \item[B\theBx.]}

\begin{document}

\noindent
It is always possible to do run two enumerate-series in parallel 
by defining two \texttt{counters}--- \texttt{Ax} and \texttt{Bx}.
\begin{enumerate}
  \itemA Series A--- point \# 1
  \itemB Series B--- point \# 1
  \itemA Series A--- point \# 2
  \itemB Series B--- point \# 2
  \itemB Series B--- again
  \itemB Series B--- once more
  \itemA Series A--- next point\ldots\ probably \# 3
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very ingenious!

Comment: Thanks@Bernard ! I thought it should be simple-to-use, too.

Comment: Thank you. It's simple and easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

You can, using the `series` and the `resume*` keys from enumitem, but it can be tedious to code if you have really long lists.

The idea is to define a first series, with the counter prefixed with the letter A, and another series, with B as prefix, to end each series after an item, then start the other series for a single item end end it the resume the first series, and so on. Here is a small code sto show how it goes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

 \begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=A\arabic*., topsep=0pt, series=A]
\item First item
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=B\arabic*., topsep=0pt, series=B]
\item Second item
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=A]
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=B]
\item Fourth item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edit,@leandriis!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax within the document itself is simpler if some commands are defined to represent the enumerate counter the right way. Then a list can be defined using `enumitem`'s commands to set the label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcount\a
\def\calternum#1{\expandafter\c@lternum\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\c@lternum#1{%
    \ifodd#1%
        \a=\number#1%
        \advance\a by 1%
        \divide\a by 2%
        A\the\a%
    \else%
        \a=\number#1%
        \divide\a by 2%
        B\the\a%
    \fi
}
\makeatother
\AddEnumerateCounter{\calternum}{\c@lternum}{A99}

\newlist{alternum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[alternum]{
    label=\calternum*.
}
\begin{document}
\begin{alternum}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \item Third item
    \item Fourth item
    \item Fifth item
    \item Sixth item
    \item Seventh item
\end{alternum}
\end{document}
```

[image]