# How I can enumerate with A1, B1, C1

Tags: enumerate

How I can enumerate like A1, B1, C1, and   A2,B2,C2 by using enumerate package.

Comment: There is no `enumrate` package. Are you specifically requiring the use of the [`enumerate` package](//ctan.org/pkg/enumerate), or are [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) options also okay?

Comment: Are A1, B1, C1 and A2, B2, C2  supposed to be in two different enumerate environments or inside of the same environment? Probably a sketch of the expected output would help clarify your request.

Comment: @nour have a look here -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549384/enumerate-a-list-with-two-parallel-prefixes -- and see the answer below

Comment: To the close voters: there are currently 3 close votes saying that this needs more detail or clarity. That's not going to help the OP! At time of writing, it has only been 5 hours, and they seem to be a new user; let's give the OP a chance, please :)

Comment: @cmhughes a closure does not mean "this question should be removed and forgotten", it is an invitation to the OP to edit the question. Many new users perceive it as a rejection of their question but that is not how the system is intended to work - the site does not make it clear to them what the reasons behind the site mechanics are, but that is a different discussion. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98022/how-soon-should-i-vote-to-close.

Comment: @nour did the answer below meet your requirement

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{Ax}
\newcounter{Bx}

\newcommand{\itemA}{%
    \addtocounter{Ax}{1}
    \item[A\theAx.]}
\newcommand{\itemB}{%
    \addtocounter{Bx}{1}
    \item[B\theBx.]}

\begin{document}
    \noindent \textbf{Case I}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \itemA Series A
        \itemB Series B
        \itemA Series A
        \itemB Series B
        \itemB Series B
        \itemB Series B
        \itemA Series A
    \end{enumerate}

    \noindent \textbf{Case II}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=A\arabic*.,  series=A]
        \item First item
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=B\arabic*.,  series=B]
        \item Second item
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}[resume*=A]
        \item Third item
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}[resume*=B]
        \item Fourth item
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```